# 2 activities results in 2 icons after install

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 2 activities connected through a button press but when I install the app I am getting 2 icons.

activity one

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_street_light_activity);
```

activity two

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.droid_mode);
```

I am getting two icons respectively for both activity which opens up respective xml files

Comment: can you post your manifest code ?

Answer (score 4):

Remove

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

in your manifest from the activity that should not have a separate symbol. This intent filter defines possible entry points of your application and normally you should only have one defined.